# In FLASK Is there a way to run a python function while the page is open?

Tags: python, flask

I got the FLASK app in which one of the routes renders a Folium Map with specific parameters. The folium map is loaded into an iframe which is being refreshed every x minutes. The map generation is triggered by html form.

Flask portion:

```
@app.route('/hermesmap', methods=['GET','POST']) 
def hermesMap():  
 
if request.method == "POST": 
    userName = request.form['username'] 
    password = request.form['password'] 
    server = request.form['server']  
    server = server[8:-1]
    ascii_pass = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(password.encode("ASCII"))

    sshpass = str(ascii_pass)
    
    sshpass = sshpass.replace("b","")
    sshpass = sshpass.replace("\'","")
    hermesMapGen.mapUpdate(userName,sshpass,server)
      

return render_template("hermesMap.html")
```

"hermesMapGen" is generating a folium map with inserted parameters and that is the function that needs to be called every five minutes, so the map will have the updated data.

This is the HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{%block content%}
 
  <div class="custom-height-map" style="position:relative;padding-top:42.25%;border-style:solid;border-width:6px;">
  <iframe src="{{url_for('static',filename='sfMarketMap.html')}}" id='hermesmap' frameborder="0" allowfullscreen
      style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe>
  </div>
  
  <script>
          window.setInterval(function() {
              reloadIFrame()
          }, 300000);
  
          function reloadIFrame() {
              console.log('reloading..');
              document.getElementById('hermesmap').contentWindow.location.reload();
          }
      </script>


{%endblock%}
</html>
```

Is there a way that I can run the function that generates the map while the map page is open in the browser?

Thanks beforehand

Update:
As of the moment I was able to find a workaround with javascript.
I put the following code in the initial form page forcing it to simulate a "click" even every x minutes, but i think there should be a better/correct way of doing this.

```html
<script>
    var btn = document.querySelector("[name='lookup']");
//console.log(btn);
setInterval(function(){
btn.click();
},200000);

//Handling of click event
btn.onclick=function(){ 
console.log('clicked');
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the right direction.

Keep on using `setInterval` but this time do a `fetch` call to the server and get latest data.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) about fetch.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your response. I looked through "fetch" and if my understanding of the concept is correct it's basically doing almost the same thing as i did in the workaround except It will be storing the form values as separate vars. Am i right or am I missing something?

Comment: Using `fetch` will do the following 1) get latest data from the server 2) modify the DOM in order reflect latest changes to the user. It is the "cleanest" way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I will investigate it. The question will be marked answer though.